# How can i store the result of SRANDMEMBER with a COUNT argument in a SET?

Tags: php, redis

I an using phpredis and i have something like below:
    $qrand = $redis->sRandMember('qall',25);
Is there a simple way of storing the resulting array in a SET other than looping and adding to the set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compose a Lua script that does that for you. Something like the following should work:

```
 EVAL "redis.replicate_commands() redis.call('SADD',KEYS[2],unpack(redis.call('SRANDMEMBER', KEYS[1],ARGV[1]))" 2 qall tmp 25
```

**Note**: this works only with Redis v3.2 and above due to randomness.